# Creating a Linux Desktop Envoriment

Tags: linux, desktop

Suppose I want to create my own desktop envoriment for Linux, **without X.** Like Google with the Android did. Where do I start? Is it actually a normal application that just draws stuff, and starts after the kernel boot? And how does it draw it? Using OpenGL or is there something more generic? And graphics drivers, how is it going? You should develop custom graphics drivers for your desktop or it comes with the Linux kernel?

Note: It's for normal PCs and not embedded devices.

Thanks.

Comment: I really recommend you **DO** reconsider using X when writing a Linux desktop environment ;)

Comment: Oh, I don't think I really going to write my own desktop environment, it's just a curiosity question. Android doesn't use X.

Comment: It this is done without X these probably paint directly to the framebuffer (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framebuffer) (iirc XFCE and GTK support this ; and mplayer and ...) but I'll be a lot easier to have a solid foundation to build upon...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: [DirectFB](http://www.directfb.org/) (and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectFB)).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the frame buffer device.
There are a few toolkits that render directly to the frame buffer for embedded device - even fully featured toolkits like [Qt](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.2/qtopiacore.html) and [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/embedded.htm#wxdfb) can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could study how OS X works in some detail.

You're probably best advised to keep most of the X server... it has a set of good device drivers already, and they're a very large part of the work.

Comment: *study how OS X works* How is that possible if OS X is proprietary?

Comment: Apple are quite open about the architecture, and GnuSTEP is similar in a lot of ways.